# How are clickable elements actually implemented in modern websites and how can I simulate clicks?

Tags: javascript, html, accessibility, wai-aria, screen-readers

I'm trying to scrape all actionable elements from a webpage--things like buttons, links, etc. Thanks to accessibility features, it's pretty easy to find what should be clickable. However, many buttons have different semantics.

For example, a small excerpt from a page in Google Docs:

```html
<div
  id="alignRightButton"
  class="goog-toolbar-toggle-button goog-toolbar-button goog-inline-block"
  role="button"
  aria-disabled="false"
  aria-pressed="false"
  style="user-select: none;"
  aria-hidden="false"
  data-tooltip="Right align (⌘+Shift+R)"
  aria-label="Right align (⌘+Shift+R)"
>
  <div
    class="goog-toolbar-button-outer-box goog-inline-block"
    aria-hidden="true"
    style="user-select: none;"
  >
    <div
      class="goog-toolbar-button-inner-box goog-inline-block"
      style="user-select: none;"
    >
      <div class="docs-icon goog-inline-block " style="user-select: none;">
        <div
          class="docs-icon-img-container docs-icon-img docs-icon-align-right"
          aria-hidden="true"
          style="user-select: none;"
        >
          &nbsp;
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The outermost div should be clickable, but I have no idea how that click is handled. Calling `.click()` on the element doesn't seem to activate its functionality, nor does the following:

```
var simulateClick = function(elem) {
  var evt = new MouseEvent("click", {
    bubbles: true,
    cancelable: true,
    view: window
  });
  var canceled = !elem.dispatchEvent(evt);
};
```

I also tried adding breakpoints on the page on mouse down, but the code is too obfuscated to really tell what's going on.

So, two questions:

1) How do "modern" sites like google docs actually handle clicks?

2) How do screen readers that interpret ARIA tags send back their actions to the webpage?

Comment: it appears that they trigger on mousedown not on click. If you inspect the element and go to event listeners you can remove them one by one. By deleting all the click handlers it still worked fine, delete the mousedown handlers and the button stops working.